# Save an SQL object to a file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs

I need to save the object `rows` in a file or save it to a JSON file.

```js
app.get('/getposts', (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query('Select * from posts', (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err) console.log(rows);
    else
      console.log(err);

    res.send(rows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
fs.writeFile('filename.json', JSON.stringify(rows), err => err && console.log(err));
```

This will stringify `rows` and write it to `filename.json`.